# Errno 13 permission denied on gcloud VM Instance

Tags: virtual-machine, instance, gcloud, permission-denied

I used this code on Gcloud Instance:

```
from PIL import Image
from PIL import ImageOps
filename = 'marmoreio_red_2.jpg'
img = Image.open(filename)

val = 10    #--- pixels to be cropped

#--- a new image with a border of 10 pixels on all sides
#--- also notice fill takes in the color of white as (255, 255, 255)
new_img = ImageOps.expand(img, border = val, fill = (0, 0, 255))

#--- cropping the image above will not result in any black portion
cropped = new_img.crop((val, val, 150, 150))

cropped.save('img_teste.jpg','JPEG')
```

The code is ok, but did'nt work just on Gcloud Instance. I received this message:

```
fp = builtins.open(filename, "w+b")
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'img_teste.jpg'
```

I tried several approachs like this:

```
 https://www.skynats.com/blog/how-to-fix-the-ftp-permission-denied-error-in-google-cloud-platform/
```

But I don´t have this file:

```
 /etc/apache2/sites-available/wordpress.conf
```

Here some additional information about my Instance:
[image]
[image]

I'm crazy with this, some suggestion, please?

Answer (score 2):

I got it.
Change the ownership of the directory: If the user running the Python code does not have write permissions to the directory, you can try changing the ownership of the directory to the user by using the chown command:

```
sudo chown -R user:user directory_path.
```

Comment: what is the user and directory_path to be specific?